# Changing order of integration in relation to the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

In a lot of my engineering textbooks the order of integration on improper integrals is mindlessly swapped in proofs regarding properties of the Fourier Transform. This has always bothered me: when I look up when this can be done, I find theorems which heavily restrict the conditions on the input functions, for example requiring absolute integrability and integration over a definite area. At the same time, functions like $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$, $\cos(t)$ and constants are used in Fourier Transforms and it is assumed that these properties apply, even though these functions are not absolutely integrable. I have found the unfamiliar term "tempered distributions" a lot which supposedly helps this against this problem, but I am really not well-versed in distribution theory. My question is: are the operations made by these engineers allowed using the constraints that the Fourier Transforms of the input functions $f(t), h(t)$ exist, even including the delta distributions present in some of these transforms?

I do not have a background in mathematics, thus engineering mathematics are the only tool on which I can really rely here. I have a few examples of steps made below:

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(q)h(t-q)e^{-i2\pi F t}dqdt = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(q)h(t-q)e^{-i2\pi F t}dtdq$

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t - q)e^{i2\pi F q}dFdq = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t - q)e^{i2\pi F q}dqdF$

Comment: I suggest you change the notation you used. "$f$" appears as both variable of integration and as a function to be integrated

Comment: @AlexOrtiz That is almost assuredly a typographical error.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz thank you for the suggestion, I will change it.

Comment: Why not looking at an introductory course on distributions ... if you want to do Fourier transform of such functions, that's the rigorous way to do it. If not you indeed need integrability or positivity to write integrals and use Fubini ... it is a bit like learning about rational numbers and asking about pi without wanting to learn about real numbers

Comment: @LL3.14 I think that indeed would be a worthwhile investment. Would you happen to know some introductory books which also show the relation between the Fourier Transform and distributions?

Comment: Unfortunately most of the courses and references I know are in french, in particular the foundational book of Laurent Schwartz, but I was told that one of the main references in english is  *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I: Distribution Theory and Fourier Analysis* by Hormander.

Comment: @LL3.14 I will take a look, thanks a lot for the recommendation.